# Maven 3 plugin that only runs on parent

Tags: maven-plugin

I created a maven plugin (plugin api 3.0.4 + plugin annotations 3.2) that should only run on the parent (for multi module projects). Is there a way to do that in the Mojo instead of telling the user to run it with "-N" (non recursive) Option?

```
@aggregator true
```

within comments didn't work

thx in advance